# Intersection between a parametric equation and a linear equation

Tags: functions, parametric

2Consider the parametric functions $f_1, f_2$ with $$f_1(x) = 3(60-x)\cdot \sin(3x)$$ and $$ f_2(x) = 3(60-x)\cdot \cos(3x).$$ 
Suppose you have a linear function: $$f_3 (x) = 1.5 x$$

How does one then calculate $f_1 \cap f_3$ and $f_2 \cap f_3$?

Comment: Do you mean $r(x) = (f_1(x), f_2(x))$ is a parametric function, and you want to find where it intersects with the line $y=1.5x$?

Comment: Yes, of course. My math background including the proper terminology is a little bit rusty.

Comment: Have you tried writing the line as a parametric equation as well?

Comment: No, I didn't. How would you do that? 1.5 = y/x seems wrong.

Comment: @Maltram, how would you define an arbitrary point on the line in terms of x? In other words, you're making x your parameter.

Comment: x = x and y = 2/3x ?

Comment: @Maltram $(x,y) = (x,1.5x)$. Also, (3/2 = 1.5)

Comment: Now, what does it mean for two parametric curves to intersect? What is happening with respect to the components of each curve when intersection occurs?

Comment: The functions for x and y respectively have to be equal in order for the point to be "in" both functions. I guess I got I now. Thanks you two. If either one of you wants to write an answer I will happily accept it.

Comment: There's still some work to be done in doing that, though. If you complete the calculation, you can also add an answer! If not, you can edit your post to include your work and explain where you're unable to proceed.